# Proof about subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a non-empty subset of$ G$

a) Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if for all $a,b \in H$, one has $ab^{-1} \in H$

Approach: We have to show both directions

1) if $a,b \in H$ and $ab^{-1} \in H$ then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

We need to show three things

i) $1_G \in H $

ii) $H$ is closed

iii) All elements in H have inverses in $H$

i) $a,b \in H $, so $ab^{-1}\in H$   $b,a\in H$,so $ba^{-1}\in H$. This implies that $ab^{-1}ba^{-1}\in H$ which implies $1_G \in H$

ii) I am stuck here. How can you get $ab$ by just taking products of $ab^{-1}$ and $ba^{-1}$

Comment: First take $e = a$ in order to show that $b^{-1}$ is in $H$.

Answer (score 3):

For 3, for any $b \in H$, we know $eb^{-1}=b^{-1} \in H$.  So for 2, for any $a \in H$, $a(b^{-1})^{-1}=ab \in H$, so $H$ is closed

Comment: Thank you. I didn't take into account I could take a or b as the identity element

Comment: The other direction is almost trivial right?

Comment: @TheMathNoob Yes of course